# Ruby on Rails Google API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api

I'm currently doing a Ruby on Rails project where I try to query from the Google Calendar API. I'm using this line of code:

```
service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
```

and I have the gem `google-api-client` in my Gemfile. However, when I try to run the app with this line, it fails saying that it is Unknown Constant: Google Apis. If I try to put in the line that I've seen on StackOverflow, where I put `require 'google/apis/calendar_v3'` in the ruby file, it fails. I've spent 4 hours online trying to find anyone with a similar solution. If I try another API, like `require 'google/apis/drive_v2'`, it works fine, just calendar. :(

Comment: Try taking reference from this site,it worked for me.
http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/using-the-google-api-ruby-client-with-google-calendar-api/

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact error messages? The one that you call "Unknown Constant", and the one where using `require` "fails".

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me on Rails 4.2.1 -- Note that there are two requires.

```
require 'google/apis'
=> true
require 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
=> true
service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
=> #<Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService:0x007fca01ae60a0 @root_url="https://www.googleapis.com/", @base_path="calendar/v3/", @upload_path="upload/calendar/v3/", @batch_path="batch", @client_options=#<struct Google::Apis::ClientOptions application_name="unknown", application_version="0.0.0", proxy_url=nil, use_net_http=false>, @request_options=#<struct Google::Apis::RequestOptions authorization=nil, retries=0, header=nil, timeout_sec=nil, open_timeout_sec=20>>
```

My gem file contains:

```
gem 'google-api-client', '0.9'
```